# Make tikzpicture bar chart go from 0 - 100

Tags: pgfplots

The bar-chart generated with the code below is in the y-axis not beginning from 0 and not ending at 100. Instead it is showing from min to max of my numbers. How do I change it to show the scale from 0 to 100?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
enlargelimits=0.10,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
symbolic x coords={Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {(Test1,40) (Test2,60) (Test3,30.1) (Test4,88.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(Test1,70) (Test2,89.1) (Test3,42.3) (Test4,71.2)};
\legend{Test one,Test two}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd just need to add `ymax=100` to the `axis` options, but because you have `enlargelimits` you also need to disable that for the y-axis, by changing from `enlargelimits` to `enlarge x limits`.

There are multiple strategies for avoiding the overlap between the numbers and adjacent bars, three are illustrated in the code below:

1. Increasing the space between the bars, by adding `bar shift=<length>` to each `\addplot`.
2. Increasing the width of the bars.
3. Reducing the font size of the numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\begin{document}
%Increase the space between bars, by adding a bar shift to each addplot:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,ymax=100,
enlarge x limits=0.15,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
symbolic x coords={Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot +[bar shift=8pt] coordinates {(Test1,40) (Test2,60) (Test3,30.1) (Test4,88.2)};
\addplot +[bar shift=-8pt] coordinates {(Test1,70) (Test2,89.1) (Test3,42.3) (Test4,71.2)};
\legend{Test one,Test two}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%Make the bars wider:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,ymax=100,
enlarge x limits=0.2, % modified
bar width=18pt,  %%% <-------- added
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
symbolic x coords={Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
]
\addplot coordinates {(Test1,40) (Test2,60) (Test3,30.1) (Test4,88.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(Test1,70) (Test2,89.1) (Test3,42.3) (Test4,71.2)};
\legend{Test one,Test two}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


%Reduce the font size of the numbers:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,ymax=100,
enlarge x limits=0.2,
legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
symbolic x coords={Test1,Test2,Test3,Test4},
xtick=data,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords align={vertical},
every node near coord/.append style={font=\tiny}%%% <-------- added
]
\addplot coordinates {(Test1,40) (Test2,60) (Test3,30.1) (Test4,88.2)};
\addplot coordinates {(Test1,70) (Test2,89.1) (Test3,42.3) (Test4,71.2)};
\legend{Test one,Test two}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, this made it! Since im already here, do you possible have an idea how to separate the numbers above each bar so they don't overlap the bars? Like adding some margins or similar, just a little bit. Example on 30.1 and 71.2 in your example image.

Comment: @J.Smith See my updated answer.